# How to take backup / Download Azure Analysis Services Data models (.bim) file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, database-backups, datamodel, azure-analysis-services

I am doing a kind of comparison between a .bim files of UAT and PROD environment. I want to download the .bim file from Prod and UAT AAS (Azure Analysis Services) and perform the comparison. I am unable to do so. I tried Backup-ASBackup, it is not downloaded the actual .bim file in fact it creates some kind of compressed file in that I can't see the actual .bim file code.

I have seen few links but they were just performing a backup of data models for disaster management.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot take backup and download Azure Analysis Services Data models (.bim) file using powershell.

**Reason:** By default, `Backup-ASDatabase`cmdlet creates a <`filename.abf`> which does not allow you to extract the files because the file is compressed with Unicode encoding and this file can be only used to `Restore-ASDatabase` in case of disaster recovery.

> You can download Azure Analysis Services Data models (.bim) file using Azure portal.

Select your **Analysis services** => Under **Models** => Select **Manage** => Select the models which you want to download the (.bim) file using **Open in Visual studio**.

[image]

The downloaded zip folder contains "`SMPROJ`" & "`BIM`" file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Cheekatlapradeep-MSFT, my purpose was to perform automation by comparing same data models after production deployment. I know the manual process, but failing to perform automation end to end.

Comment: there is a solution but that solution is not end to end, that's means is we have enter credentials manually into this solution.

Comment: param (
    [String]
    $envName1 = "asazure://aspaaseastus.asazure.windows.net/myaas",
)

$loadInfo = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$server1 = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server1.Connect($envName1)
$num = 0
$filepath = "E:\Data\Processing_State.txt"

foreach ($d in $server.Databases)
{
 Write-Output("Database: {0}; LastRefresh: {1} LastProcessed: {2} Size: {3}MB" -f $d.Name,
 $d.LastUpdate, $d.Lastprocessed, ($d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024).ToString("#,##0"))
 $num = $num+$d.EstimatedSize/1024/1024
}

Comment: Hi CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT, Is it possible using by Model object (TMSL)? i seen in documentation. As per documentation it should return but object when i tried it is returning xml only with execution details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/model-object-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions